# Create dropdown inside table cell using result of string.match()

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have following string which looks like a JavaScript object.

```
             fields { 
              allowed_values { 
                             display_name: "A" 
                             } 
              allowed_values {
                             display_name: "B" 
                             } 
             }
```

I want to get the the values in quotes (`"A", "B"`) from this string but also want to show these values as items in a dropdown inside a table cell. My problem is that I am unable to get these values as an array suitable for dropdown items.

I am getting the values in quotes as shown in the following piece of code, and getting `"A""B"`.

```
     <DataCell>
        {fields.match(/(?!^)".*?"/g)}
     </DataCell>
```

I need help in figuring out how to create a Dropdown using these values. Something like the following code but a traversable array/list passed to the `items` parameter

```
<DataCell>
    <Dropdown items={fields.match(/(?!^)".*?"/g)} />
</DataCell>
```

I would appreciate some help regarding how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the look-around assertion

```js
const data = 'fields { allowed_values { display_name: "A" } allowed_values { display_name: "B" } }';

const matchings = data.match(/(?<=display_name: ")\w+/g);

console.log(matchings);
```

Comment: Thank you, @MoxxiManagarm. Since I am dynamically creating both the dropdown and table cell, I am not sure how to use constants and variables inside HTML tags in Typescript.

Comment: You don't need to, I only created those variables for the example. Just replace the regexes.